# How can I use the ipv6 address in the android phone?

Tags: android, sockets, ipv6

Turn on cell phone traffic

[image: adb shell connect with phone]

I can't use the IPv6 addr to make a socket connection with my server.

When I use IPv4, it works! But when I use IPv6, it doesn't work.

Here is my client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT 1234
#define MAXDATASIZE 100


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int socketfd;
    ssize_t send_num,recv_num;
    char send_buf[MAXDATASIZE],recv_buf[MAXDATASIZE],wel[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in6 server;
    struct hostent* remote_host;

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage:%s <IP address>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if((socketfd=socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)
    {
        perror("socket() error.");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin6_family=AF_INET6;
    server.sin6_port=htons(PORT);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, argv[1], &server.sin6_addr) < 0 ) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(1) ;
    }

    if((connect(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server)))==-1)
    {
        perror("connect() error.");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((recv(socketfd,wel,MAXDATASIZE,0))==-1)
    {
        perror("[!] Receive welcome message fail.");
        exit(1);
    }
    wel[sizeof(wel)-1]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", wel);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("[*] Input string:");
        scanf("%s",&send_buf);
        send_buf[strlen(send_buf)]='\0';

        if((strlen(send_buf))>100)
        {
            printf("[!] Only supports sending fewer than 100 characters.");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((send_num=send(socketfd,send_buf,MAXDATASIZE,0))==-1)
        {
        perror("send() error.");
        exit(1);
        }

        if((recv_num=recv(socketfd,recv_buf,MAXDATASIZE,0))==-1)
        {
            perror("recv() error.");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("[>] Received reverse string:%s\n",recv_buf);
        if(!strcmp(recv_buf,"tiuq"))
        {
            close(socketfd);
            break;
        }
    }
    close(socketfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my server code:

```
if((socketfd=socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)
{
    perror("socket() error.");
    exit(1);
}

setsockopt(socketfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&opt,sizeof(opt));

bzero(&server,sizeof(server));
server.sin6_family=AF_INET6;
server.sin6_port=htons(PORT);
server.sin6_addr=in6addr_any;

if((bindfd=bind(socketfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)))==-1)
{
    perror("bind() error.");
    exit(1);
}

if((listenfd=listen(socketfd,MAXNUMCLINET))==-1)
{
    perror("listen() error.");
    exit(1);
}

if((connectfd=accept(socketfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&addrlen))==-1)
{
    perror("accept() error.");
    exit(1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: Your second screenshot shown you trying to have your client connect to IPv6 `2607:8700:109...`, but your first screenshot shows an IPv6 address of `2409:8890:8e20:...`.  What is your server's actual IPv6 address? Are you sure your client and server are on the same network? Are you sure your client is connecting to the correct IP? What errors are you actually receiving?

Comment: The first screenshot shows an ipv6 address when open the cellphone data  ,it looks like it has a global ipv6 address .the second screenshot shows use the client connect to my server which have a ipv6 address .2409:8890:8e20:... is the cell phone ip address  ,2607:8700:109:....is the server  ip address ,and I want to make a TCP connect between them.The cell phone sopported 4G/VoLTE

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! @RemyLebeau .your comments help me very!